# PHP show next results in new row in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

I have got a html table which I am using to show my products and I have the following code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<td>
 <!--START OF PRODUCT-->    
        <div>
        <h3>'.$row['productname'] . '</h3><img src="'.$row['thumb']. '" width="100%">

              <div>
            <div class="panel">
                    <h5>From £' . $row['price']. '</h5>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <p>'. $row['shortdesc']. '</p>

                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="large-12 columns">
                     </div>
                     <form name="sign" action="http://www.shapeways.com/cart/addMultiple" method="GET" class="custom">
        <input type="hidden" name="model_id[]" value="'. $row['id']. '">
<label for="customDropdown1">Material/Colour</label>
        <select name="material_id[]" id="customDropdown1" class="medium">'.$row['materials']. '</select>
      <div class="row">
                     <div class="large-6 columns">
                     <a href="#'. $row['id']. '" class="button secondary">Information</a>
                     </div>
        <div class="row">
                     <div class="large-6 columns">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" id="add_to_cart" alt="add to cart" value="Buy Now">

        </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>        
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
    </td>
';

  }



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want it to show 3 rows from the database and then when it selects the next 3 for that to be on the next line in the html table. and for this to be repeated.

I hope this is clear and some help would be great.

Code for first answer:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">


       <?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");



      echo "<tr>";
$start = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $cell = '<td>
 <!--START OF PRODUCT-->    
        <div>
        <h3>'.$row['productname'] . '</h3><img src="'.$row['thumb']. '" width="100%">

              <div>
            <div class="panel">
                    <h5>From £' . $row['price']. '</h5>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <p>'. $row['shortdesc']. '</p>

                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="large-12 columns">
                     </div>
                     <form name="sign" action="http://www.shapeways.com/cart/addMultiple" method="GET" class="custom">
        <input type="hidden" name="model_id[]" value="'. $row['id']. '">
<label for="customDropdown1">Material/Colour</label>
        <select name="material_id[]" id="customDropdown1" class="medium">'.$row['materials']. '</select>
      <div class="row">
                     <div class="large-6 columns">
                     <a href="#'. $row['id']. '" class="button secondary">Information</a>
                     </div>
        <div class="row">
                     <div class="large-6 columns">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" id="add_to_cart" alt="add to cart" value="Buy Now">

        </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>        
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
    </td>';

    if($counter%3 == 0 && $start == 1){
        echo "</tr><tr>", $cell;
    }
    else{
        echo $cell;
    }
    $started = 1;
    $counter++;
}
echo "</tr>";





mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</table>
```

Comment: So you're asking how to wrap your `td`s with a `tr` for your table?

Comment: No, i want it to wrap the td s with a tr tag after 3 td s are used

Comment: That's what I asked.  I figured it was implied that we would wrap 3 `td`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should get you what you want (if I understand you correctly)... Just replace the contents of `$cell` with the code you have above in your `echo`

```
$counter = 1;

echo "<tr>";
$started = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($yourArray)){

    $cell = "Put the code you were echoing above in here";

    if($counter%3 == 0 && $started == 1){
        echo $cell, "</tr><tr>";
    }
    else{
        echo $cell;
    }
    $started = 1;
    $counter++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Hi i tried this and it did not work i also had to change the "" in the $cell to '' for dreamweaver to stop telling me it was wrong. I have added my code to my question, just in case it was me making an error.

Comment: In the code you have put `if($counter%3 == 0 && $start == 1){`  not `if($counter%3 == 0 && $started == 1){`. My fault, I edited it!

Comment: You also need to change the `$start = 0` declaration to `$started = 0`

Comment: Lastly, you need to flip `echo "</tr><tr>", $cell;` to `echo $cell, "</tr><tr>";`